# how to avoid threshold violation in visual studio 2012 ultimate load testing?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, load-testing, web-performance

[image]

i have successfully run the load test but  i am getting too much threshold violation,  what is the reason for it And how to reduce the threshold violation.

Answer (score 1):

Threshold violation say that the named computer(s) are close to being overloaded.

If the named computer(s) are the computers running the tests then you should consider spreading the load using controllers and agents, or using more powerful computers. In this case the load test may be reporting, or close to reporting, incorrect results because it is on the verge of being overloaded.

If the named computer(s) are the servers in the system being tested then the violations show that the servers are close to their limit and will not support many more virtual users. In this case the performance test has found a limitation of the system under test.